# strophe xmpp client with ejabberd server getting repeated rid error (Getting 504 - timed out response for polling)

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

We have a system setup where we use Stophe to connect to ejabberd over
BOSH running through HA-Proxy. When our clients are idle, they seem to
be hitting the timeout (@ 1.1 * 60 seconds), which aborts the
outstanding long-poll. The library then appears to make the next
long-poll using the same rid. ejabberd shows repeating RID and returns error.

Comment: i am also facing the same issue and unable to resolve it.